# How does one find the coefficients in the solution to the Laplace equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, potential-theory

I'm reading [this](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluidhtml/node65.html#e3.58y). Equation (522) gives the general solution to the Laplace equation. What I'm stuck about, is how to determine the coefficients $a_m$, $\beta_m$, and $\theta_m$ for non-trivial boundary conditions.

For instance, setting $r=1$ in the equation for $\psi$ works. But then I don't know how to determine $\theta_m$.

In particular, how are the coefficients determined for boundary conditions, of the most general kind possible? For example, flow around a circle or a wedge? The site I reference doesn't really elaborate on how the coefficients are obtained for these cases.

Comment: The coefficients are found by applying prescribed boundary conditions, typically (but not always) given in terms of either the function $\psi$ or its normal derivative to a constant contour.  For example, at $r=1$, one might be given $\psi(1,\theta)$ or $\frac{\partial \psi(1,\theta)}{\partial \theta}$.  Then, to find the coefficients, we exploit the orthogonality of the Fourier basis functions.

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm aware. However the coefficient is given inside a sine function as $\sin(\theta-\theta_m)$. In addition, what if I want flow around a cylinder with a radius not equal to one, or a square? In addition, a quick look at the referenced page shows that there are coefficients outside the summation that must be handled. In other words, without an example, your statement seems a bit idealistic.